# What are the options for deploying files with sensitive data?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, octopus-deploy

I want to deploy file containing sensitive data. This file is in json format and depends on the environment.

Initially I intended to make a step in Octopus and expected it can deploy files depending on the environment similar how it works with sensitive variables, but I could find nothing in web UI.

The second option I am considering is something like `ansible-vault`.
 
So far I found the tool `dotnet-encrypto`, but it seems not to encode the result in base64 and it does not accept password as a command line parameter.

So, what are the alternatives?

Comment: Well, I guess you can't turn the content of the files into settings?

Comment: @jpgrassi It is possible, but quite error prone. The file is actually a google cloud credentials.

Comment: You don't? Sensitive data should go into a native encrypted store such as Azure Key Vault. You should *never* put it in a JSON file.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Or if its contents is properly encrypted. It's ok for the contents to be in decrypted form when application is deployed to the server.

Comment: There's no native encryption/decryption for JSON. Even if you are able to encrypt the value, you *still* should not be storing that in a physical file like JSON, because then it ends up in your source control. Just because something is encrypted, doesn't mean you should then go broadcast the ciphertext to the world. Use a *real* secret store.

Comment: @ChrisPratt What is wrong with storing base64 encoded encrypted file in source control? Are not we trusting cryptography anymore? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vault.html

Comment: *Never* trust cryptography. Any cipher can be potentially cracked. *Strong* encryption like SHA-2 and SHA-3 is *harder* to crack, but all any cryptanalyst needs is enough time, compute, and/or ciphertext to work with. Passwords are encrypted, but that doesn't mean that we just dump our user database for the world to see. If it's important enough to encrypt, it's important enough to restrict viewing as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dotnet-encrypto to encrypt a text to base64 using the following command :

`dotnet-encrypto encrypt -t "text-to-encrypt"`

Password doesn't accept as a command line parameter at the latest version.